# Remap single character within fontstyle definition

Tags: macros, mapping, active-characters

I have created a font from otf using autoinst to typeset some chord symbols in TeX. This font is designed (by its creator) to map character positions to certain musical symbols, like the small latin letter b is mapped to a superscripted flat sign, and so on. The conversion worked well, but i need to remap some characters to a different default output. My font switch is:

```
\def\chordfont{\fontencoding{LY1}\fontfamily{OpusChordsStd-\OpusChordsStd@figurealign\OpusChordsStd@figurestyle}\selectfont%
  % working stuff omitted
}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textchord}{\chordfont}
```

When i type

```
1: \textchord{Ab-}\\
2: \textchord{Ab\symbol{28}}
```

i get

[image: Output1]

What i want is to re-map the `-` character in a way that it outputs `\symbol{28}` by default.

So far i tried

```
%% first Try
\def\chordfont{% ...
  \def\@tempa{\symbol{28}}%
  \let-\@tempa%
}
```

and

```
%% second Try
\def\chordfont{% ...
  \catcode`-=\active\relax
  \def-\symbol{28}%
}
```

but bots tries give me an `\inaccessible` error when i run latex. I'm using pdflatex in TeXLive2017.

An abstraction could be:

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\myfirstcommand{%
  \catcode`-=\active
  \def-{\textsuperscript{-}}%
}

\makeatletter
\def\mysecondcommand{%
  \def\@tempa
  \let-\@tempa%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

A-

A\textsuperscript{-}

\myfirstcommand{A-}

\mysecondcommand{A-}

\end{document}
```

In this minimal non-working example, `\myfirstcommand` throws two exceptions: first the `\inaccessible` error, second the `- is an undefined control sequence` error. `\mysecondcommand` throws no exception, but doesn't give the desired output, either.

How do I do this right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your - is not active when you define your commands. You can do it like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\begingroup
\catcode`-=\active  
\gdef\mysecondcommand{\begingroup\catcode`-=\active \def\@tempa{XXXX}%
  \let-\@tempa\@mysecondcommand}%
\gdef\@mysecondcommand#1{#1\endgroup}
\endgroup
\makeatother

\begin{document}

A-

A\textsuperscript{-}


\mysecondcommand{A-}

A-

\end{document}
```

[image]

But I would try to reencode the font instead.

Comment: Thanks. A few follow-up questions, though:  Why doesn't `\@mysecondcommand` throw an missing argument-error when it is called within `\mysecondcommand`? Or is the `}` the argument in this case?  Why do i need to make `-` active twice? How do i reencode the font?

Comment: Why should it miss an argument? It will take what follows in the input and this is `{A-}`.  You need to make the - active for the definition and for the use. And you can reencode the font by changing the tfm and the map-file.

Comment: okay, I see now how this works. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

I'd avoid activating characters, because this would not allow you to use `\textchord` in the argument to another command. Better do replacements.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\chordfont}{%
  \usefont{LY1}{OpusChordsStd-\OpusChordsStd@figurealign\OpusChordsStd@figurestyle}{m}{n}%
  % working stuff omitted
}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\chordfont}{\usefont{U}{pzd}{m}{n}}% I don't have OpusChord

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\textchord}{m}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { - } { \symbol{56} } % use 28
  % other replacements
  \chordfont
  \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
  \group_end:
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\textchord{Ab}

\textchord{Ab-}

{\chordfont Ab\symbol{56}} % check

{\chordfont Ab-} % check

\end{document}
```

Since I don't have the font, I used Zapf Dingbats instead.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to do this without using Expl3 markup?

Comment: @Lupino What's the problem with `expl3`?

Comment: The main reason is that I have no experience with LaTeX3, so far. What I usually do is quite low level (la)tex programming with focus on speed and portability. I fear that including routines from l3 will interfer with my existing definitions and/or performance. That's also why I messed around with otftotfm instead of using lua-/xelatex to incorporate otf fonts directly into my current project. Does that make sense?